# Java/SWING error with JSlider

Tags: java, swing, jslider

**Update:** Tyler Osborne had the answer:

> Try declaring the slider variable as a final variable. When you try to refer to a variable in an enclosing scope, it must be final.

When I tried this before it just threw a load more compiler errors but now for some reason it worked. Thanks!

**Original post**
I'm trying to write a program that outputs specific information to some textboxes depending on the position of a slider. I figured that the stateChanged event of the slider was the right place to do this in. However when I use slider.getValue() in there to determine what information to place, I get a compiler error. I only just started using Java over from C++ so I don't know a lot of it yet, and I'm not managing to understand the solutions I find on google. Can anybody help me?
I put '>>' at the line that gives the error.

Compileable code:

```
package autos;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;

public class AutoVerkoop extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField txtType;
private JTextField txtModel;
private JTextField txtBouwjaar;
private JTextField txtPrijs;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                AutoVerkoop frame = new AutoVerkoop();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public AutoVerkoop() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 658, 228);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Chevrolet Avalance");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(278, 165, 131, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

    JLabel lblBmwi = new JLabel("BMW 335i");
    lblBmwi.setBounds(36, 165, 65, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblBmwi);

    JLabel lblHondaAccord = new JLabel("Honda Accord");
    lblHondaAccord.setBounds(158, 165, 92, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblHondaAccord);

    JLabel lblVolvoC = new JLabel("Volvo C70");
    lblVolvoC.setBounds(435, 165, 65, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblVolvoC);

    JLabel lblLandRoverLr = new JLabel("Land Rover LR3");
    lblLandRoverLr.setBounds(529, 165, 138, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblLandRoverLr);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
    panel.setBounds(52, 11, 537, 89);
    contentPane.add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblType = new JLabel("Merk:");
    lblType.setBounds(10, 14, 46, 14);
    panel.add(lblType);

    JLabel lblModel = new JLabel("Model:");
    lblModel.setBounds(10, 60, 46, 14);
    panel.add(lblModel);

    JLabel lblBouwjaar = new JLabel("Bouwjaar:");
    lblBouwjaar.setBounds(290, 14, 71, 14);
    panel.add(lblBouwjaar);

    JLabel lblPrijs = new JLabel("Prijs:");
    lblPrijs.setBounds(290, 60, 46, 14);
    panel.add(lblPrijs);

    txtType = new JTextField();
    txtType.setEditable(false);
    txtType.setBounds(66, 11, 133, 20);
    panel.add(txtType);
    txtType.setColumns(10);

    txtModel = new JTextField();
    txtModel.setEditable(false);
    txtModel.setBounds(66, 57, 133, 20);
    panel.add(txtModel);
    txtModel.setColumns(10);

    txtBouwjaar = new JTextField();
    txtBouwjaar.setEditable(false);
    txtBouwjaar.setBounds(371, 11, 133, 20);
    panel.add(txtBouwjaar);
    txtBouwjaar.setColumns(10);

    txtPrijs = new JTextField();
    txtPrijs.setEditable(false);
    txtPrijs.setBounds(371, 57, 133, 20);
    panel.add(txtPrijs);
    txtPrijs.setColumns(10);

    JSlider slider = new JSlider();
    slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
>>      switch(slider.getValue()) {
            case 0:
                txtType.setText("BMW");
                txtModel.setText("335i");
                txtBouwjaar.setText("2007");
                txtPrijs.setText("€42 350");
                break;
            default: break;
            }
        }
    });
    slider.setMaximum(4);
    slider.setValue(0);
    slider.setPaintTicks(true);
    slider.setMajorTickSpacing(1);
    slider.setBounds(54, 111, 537, 51);
    contentPane.add(slider);
}
}
```

The compiler log is this:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Cannot refer to the non-final local variable slider defined in an enclosing scope

at autos.AutoVerkoop$2.stateChanged(AutoVerkoop.java:124)
at javax.swing.JSlider.fireStateChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JSlider$ModelListener.stateChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.fireStateChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.setRangeProperties(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.setMaximum(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JSlider.setMaximum(Unknown Source)
at autos.AutoVerkoop.<init>(AutoVerkoop.java:135)
at autos.AutoVerkoop$1.run(AutoVerkoop.java:35)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can anybody help me solve this problem?

Comment: Try declaring the slider variable as a final variable. When you try to refer to a variable in an enclosing scope, it must be final.

Comment: Either what @TylerOsborne recommends or declare the JSlider as a field in the class.

Comment: Other issues: your exception message tells you that you're trying to run code that doesn't compile, something you should **never** do. Fix the errors that the compiler gives you **before** trying to run your program since the error messages from the compiler will be very informative. Also in the future, try to use a more appropriate question title. `"Java/SWING error with JSlider"` tells us nothing about your problem which really is in fact nothing more than a `"Cannot refer to the non-final local variable"` problem.

Comment: Also, I would use a JComboBox, not a JSlider for your car models, since the JComboBox can hold differing numbers of items and in fact can hold quite a lot, without breaking your GUI as your JSlider would. Also, while null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, you will eventually run into difficulties when using them. They won't resize components when the GUI resizes, they are a difficult to enhance or maintain, they fail when placed in scrollpanes, they look awful when viewed on other platforms.

Comment: Instead you will want to learn and use the Swing layout managers.